# What is the lowest limit of Force strength one has to possess to extract information from another person's mind?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force

In the Star Wars series, the Jedi have "mind tricks" that simply put a suggestion in another person's mind.

[image: These aren't the droids you are looking for]

[image: You will remove these restraints, and leave the cell with the door open]

As from these examples, the trick is fairly simple, and clearly even a novice is able to do it. However, Kylo Ren is not your average Padawan. He clearly has quite a bit of strength to do such things as immobilize his opponents and laser bolts, and even survive a blast from a Bowcaster.

How strong does a Jedi need to be to be able to forcibly *extract* information from another person's mind?

Comment: I think you're putting the Jedi mind trick and Kylo's mind reading on the same shelf. They're not.

Comment: You need to be at least 7 powerful. 6 powerful won't do it.

Comment: So far, the lowest in-film plank seems to be *Rey-strong*.

Comment: @Gallifreian - I actually think she’s closer to the top of the power scale.

Comment: @Gallifreian yes, I do understand that. I am merely comparing the two because they both fall under the "power over the mind" category.

Comment: @Adamant  -  why?

Comment: @Gallifreian - 1) Is the main protagonist of a *Star Wars* film, 2) Can deflect Kylo’s mind probe back on him, 3) wins the tug-of-war for Kylo’s lightsaber then 4) beats Kylo in a lightsaber fight and 5) all this with almost certainly minimal training (even if she was trained in the past, she’s been on Jakku for most of her life).

Comment: @Adamant  -  novice's luck. I agree with your reasoning, but taking TFA seriously in terms of lore is hard.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Not really all that hard. It fits in pretty well. I could make comparisons to Luke and Anakin’s skills, but they didn’t have prior training (whereas Rey likely did). But if she didn’t (and we shall see), that simply puts her higher on the power scale. There’s a great deal we still don’t know about Rey.

Comment: This question has appeared in the close queue as *primarily opinion-based*. Would you consider editing it so that it doesn't appear as such? Like `Who is the weakest Force user to use the mind probe?`, or similar.

Answer (score 3):

### Probably about as much as the Grand Inquisitor

This power is often called a [mind probe](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_probe_(Force_power)).  The mind probe is often invasive and painful, as seen in some of the following cases, and is thus probably a dark side force power (or most often employed by the dark side).  Although it might appear that Rey used it, she was more likely simply deflecting Kylo Ren’s attempt, much as Yoda deflected, say, Dooku’s Force lightning. As such, the question of how strong a *Jedi* must be is likely somewhat ill-posed: a Jedi would probably not use or learn this power.

With regard to the strength of the practitioners we’ve seen employ this trick, we have (in likely descending order):

1. Kylo Ren
2. And by Vader, who seems to have dispensed with the hand gestures (probably just an aid, in any case):

   > “Give yourself to the dark side,” urges Vader. “It is the only way you
   >   can save your friends. Yes…your thoughts betray you. Your feelings for
   >   them are strong, especially for…”
   >
   > Vader pauses. Luke grimaces. The Emperor rises from his throne to hear
   >   what Vader will say. This is unexpected.
   >
   > “Sister! So…you have a twin sister. Obi-Wan was wise to hide her from
   >   me. But now his failure is complete. Your feelings have betrayed her,
   >   too. If you will not turn to the dark side, perhaps she will.”
   >
   > <sub>*Beware the Power of the Dark Side!*</sub>
3. Maul:

   [image]
4. **Crucially, we have also seen it used by the Grand Inquisitor.**

   While fairly strong, the Grand Inquisitor is not on the level of Maul, Vader, or Kylo. He represents likely the least powerful person we’ve seen who can perform a mind probe.

Comment: we see it also in rebels when the viceroy of the trade federation got captured (or was it cad bane?) one of the two....ashoka, mace windu and anakin I think was it trying to force probe him there (even stating that they have to stop else they would destroy his mind)

Comment: @Thomas - I think they are actually trying an extra strength mind trick. But similar, yes.